# Jenkins can not download Docker

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins to checkout source code and build image and push the image.

In Jenkins I configurate Docker just like this:

[image]

in my Jenkins Pipeline Script

pipeline {
agent none
environment {
registry = ""
registryCredential = ''
imageName = 'imageName'
dockerImage = ''
dockerHome = tool 'docker_latest'
PATH = "$dockerHome/bin:$PATH"
}

```
stages {
  stage('Prepare') {
      agent { 
        label "${config.job.agent}"
            }
            steps {
                echo "CheckOut"
                script {
                    checkout
                }
               
            }
        }
   stage('Building image') {
            steps{
                dir('jenkins-slave-savi'){
                    script {
                        dockerImage = docker.build imageName  + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    stage('Deploy Image'){
            steps {
                script {
                   docker.withRegistry(registry) {
                       dockerImage.push()
                   } 
                }
            }
    }


}
```

}

but when I run this script, I got this error:

ERROR: Failed to download pre-1.11.x URL https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest from agent: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

ERROR: Failed to download https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest.tgz from agent; will retry from master

any solutions???